# Flutter Provider's methods cant be called from classes

Tags: flutter, dart, provider

i have used provider package to manage flutter apps state, but i am facing many problems in using it.
i have defined a simple provider which has one Boolean variable and one method that change the variable value

```
     class LoadingModel with ChangeNotifier{
      bool is_loading=false;

      changeLoadingState(){
        is_loading = !is_loading;
        notifyListeners();
      }}
```

now i want to call changeLoadingState() method that defined in the provider from MyApp class in the main page and here is the main page code

```
    void main() => runApp(MyApp());

    class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ChangeNotifierProvider(
      create: (context) => LoadingModel(),
      child: MaterialApp(
        home:Scaffold(
          body: Center(
            child: Wrap(children: [
            Column(children: [
                RaisedButton(
              child: Text("hide the progress"),
              onPressed: () {
               Provider.of(context,listen: false).changeLoadingState();

                },
            )

            ],)
            ],)
          ),
        )
      ), 
    );
  }
}
```

but when i run the app the console display

Error: Could not find the correct Provider above this MyApp Widget

To fix, please:

- Ensure the Provider is an ancestor to this MyApp Widget
- Provide types to Provider
- Provide types to Consumer
- Provide types to Provider.of()
- Always use package imports. Ex: `import 'package:my_app/my_code.dart';
- Ensure the correct `context` is being used.

If none of these solutions work, please file a bug at:
https://github.com/rrousselGit/provider/issues

how i can solve this problem???

Answer (score 1):

Try this. Hope you don't get error .

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ChangeNotifierProvider<LoadingModel>(
      create: (context) => new LoadingModel(),
      child: Consumer<LoadingModel>(builder: (context, loadingModel, _) {
        return MaterialApp(
            home: Scaffold(
          body: Center(
              child: Wrap(
            children: [
              Column(
                children: [
                  RaisedButton(
                    child: Text("hide the progress"),
                    onPressed: () {
                      loadingModel.changeLoadingState();
                    },
                  )
                ],
              )
            ],
          )),
        ));
      }),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I dont understand why we have to wrap the code inside consumer widget. I thought that consumer widget can be used to refresh the ui if any changes happened in the provider data. But in my case i dont want to make any changes the main ui. I just want to call the method in the provider.
Why you wrap the code inside consumer

Comment: If you don't want to update the UI then why are you using LoadingModel?

Comment: I want to update another widget in the main page. The main page contains a button and container. When i pressed on the button, the container widget will be updated but the button itself wont be updated

Answer (score 0):

You will need to create a getter for the boolean

```
class LoadingModel with ChangeNotifier{
   bool is_loading = false;

  bool get loadingState(){
    is_loading = is_loading ? false : true;
    return is_loading;
  };
```

Then in myApp, wrap the section of the widget tree where you want it to re-build with a Consumer and can call the getter like so:

```
   Consumer<LoadingModel>(context, loadingModel, _){
   ...
   RaisedButton(
     child: Text("hide the progress"),
        onPressed: () {
           loadingModel.loadingState();
         },
    )
```